# How to have q-card take full height in q-splitter, in Quasar

Tags: html, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

We have a Vue/Quasar based project and in one of the pages want to have a splitter, with two panes, where the content takes full height in each. Right now they occupy minimal height.

```html
    <q-splitter 
      v-model="splitterModel"
      style="height: 100%; width: 100%"
      class="no-margin full-height"
      before-class="left-pane no-margin full-height"
      after-class="right-pane no-margin full-height"
    >
    <template v-slot:before>
      <q-card class="left-pane-content no-margin full-height">
        LEFT
      </q-card>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:after>
      <q-card class="right-pane-content no-margin full-height">
        RIGHT
      </q-card>
    </template>
    </q-splitter>
```

```css
.left-pane {
    background: pink;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .right-pane {
    background: pink;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .left-pane-content {
    background: #efefef;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .right-pane-content {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

The parent of the `q-splitter` is a `q-page` with the following CSS:

```css
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
```

Sample of the current output, where we want both the 'LEFT' and 'RIGHT' `q-card`s taking up full height, and eventually being individually scrollable.

[image: Sample of the current output]

Answer (score 0):

If we can use use `vh` in `height` and add `fit` I think it will work just try this code.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/JjyvXdr